# Is there a way to create a spring boot client app to read data from another Spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, web-deployment

I want to create spring boot application work as a client contains JSP files and a view controller reads the data from another spring boot application as server-side.

The server-side application work with the database using JPA.

Is there any way or resource to achieve this?

Comment: Of course, you'll just need to get the data somehow from the other spring application. Whether it's through REST or some other technology.

Comment: Thank you, Do I need any deployment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this by creating an application as an API service and sending your data and information from others to it as mentioned above like RestApi